# fullcalendar, javascript and php in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am trying to use the jQuery fullcalendar and I must set events dynamically from queries.

I must use PHP and JavaScript together for getting and setting events in the calendar.

My code doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM visita_pre"; // query
    $res = mysql_query($query);          // salvataggio risultato query
    if ($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {                            
        // se la query ha dato risultato<?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {                         
        // ciclo scansione righe risultato query
            if ($row['id'] !== null) {
                $tipo = $row['tipo'];
                $start= $row['start'];
                $end = $row['end'];
                $cell = $row['cell'];
?>
<script>
    var event = {title: 'New event', start: <?php print $start; ?>};
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
</script>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

It doesn't generate outputs and the console tells me that I have 4 syntax errors:

- 1 Unexpected end of input, and
- 2 Unexpected identifier, and
- 1 Unexpected token.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  That isn't very helpful. Do you get PHP errors? Javascript errors in your developer console? What are the values of your variables? What is the *generated output* from this php script?

Comment: I spent a long time trying to get fullcalendar to work, it is very picky regarding the time date format and the way in which the data is presented.  You will find tutorials online for variuos thing but this is a good start - http://www.jqueryajaxphp.com/fullcalendar-crud-with-jquery-and-php/

Comment: it doesn't generate outputs and the console tell me that i have 4 syntax errors: 1 Unexpected end of input, 2 Unexpected identifier and 1 Unexpected token }

Comment: @Edoardo what cal_b is asking is the javascript code as seen in the browser, the part between <script> and </script>, to see how PHP has rendered `$start`. It could also be good to show us the lines corresponding to the console errors.

Comment: thank's at all, i solved this problem, passing values into javascript variables